# JSON file parse error from delete_user method

Tags: ruby, json

I have a program that saves to a JSON file, this is my first attempt with a JSON file so I apologize if this is a very simple question.

I have a method inside of my program that parses the JSON file and deletes the information that is given by the user, called `delete_user`. While parsing the file from the `delete_user` method I get the error:

```
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/2.2.0/json/common.rb:155:in `parse': 776: unexpected token at
 'users.json' (JSON::ParserError)
        from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/2.2.0/json/common.rb:155:in `parse'
        from usertool.rb:35:in `delete_user'
        from usertool.rb:15:in `menu'
        from usertool.rb:66:in `<main>'
```

I understand that the error is telling me my JSON file isn't parsing, but what I don't understand is why..

The `delete_user` method that the error is coming from:

```
def delete_user
    hash = JSON.parse('users.json')
    delete_data = prompt("Enter username:")
    delete_data[:username] = "#{username}"
    delete_data.delete[:email_address, :member_status]
    new_json = delete_data.to_json
    delete_user if restart
end
```

Is there a issue with how I'm parsing the file, am I doing it wrong? Or is there another issue that's going way over my head?

And here's an example of the JSON file:

```
{"username":"TEST1","email_address":"TEST1","member_status":"TEST1"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## TR;DL:

This will work:

```
JSON.parse(File.read('file-name-to-be-read.json'))
```

## Why?

`json.parse [string]` parses plain JSON, but doesn't load a file. Instead, pass it a file object, and it will read the JSON inside of it.

## JSON Is A String

JSON is a way of encoding objects to a string - it is based on how javascript objects are defined (**J**ava**S**cript-**O**ption-**N**otation). It's a string - not a file saver, which means you can use it in more applications, like API's, along with saving data to files.